# Is there any way to test a loaded web page url using protractor, although it changes port number randomly and url is changing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I test a webpage using the protractor and I used expected conditions class to validate login page, and due to port is changing tests fail. Is there any way to fix this?

```
browser.wait(EC.urlContains('localhost:49153'), 10000);
browser.wait(EC.urlContains('http://localhost:49153/'), 10000).then(function() {
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your login page has any particular page title in html or even any unique elements on the page itself (such as username field) I would imagine these could also be used. Could you post some of the HTML code from your login page?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know the port number beforehand, you could get the current url and either do a match or use the node URL API.

```
const currentUrl = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
// for example, the url we are trying to get is http://localhost:12345/login/some/foo
```

### Using match

You could use regex to match. It is fun if you like regex.

```
expect(currentUrl).toMatch(/localhost:\d+\/login\/some\/foo/);
```

### Using node URL (WHATWG API):

You could also use node url API See https://nodejs.org/api/url.html
I like this version just because it is easier to read:

```
const currentHref = new URL(currentUrl);
expect(currentHref.protocol).toBe('http');
expect(currentHref.host).toBe('localhost');
// take a look at the chart, path includes path + search query
// but does not include hashes. If you have hashes, you'll need to change this.
expect(currentHref.path).toBe('/login/some/foo');
```